# FedEx Api Fatal error: Call to undefined function setEndpoint()

Tags: php, fedex

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function setEndpoint();

In which file `setEndpoin()` exist.

Comment: FedEx library included?

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$OtherIdentifiers in D:\xampp\htdocs\fedex\index.php on line 44

code is here:

$info['Reference'] = $track->CompletedTrackDetails->TrackDetails->OtherIdentifiers['1']->PackageIdentifier->Value;

Comment: `print_r($track)` chk this and share the result

Comment: there is no $OtherIdentifiers in array.

Comment: good to see u have fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these functions in your fedex-common.php5

```
function setEndpoint($var){
  if($var == 'changeEndpoint') Return false;
  if($var == 'endpoint') Return '';
}

function trackDetails($details, $spacer){
foreach($details as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value) || is_object($value)){
        $newSpacer = $spacer. '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo '<tr><td>'. $spacer . $key.'</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>';
        trackDetails($value, $newSpacer);
    }elseif(empty($value)){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$spacer. $key .'</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>';
    }else{
        echo '<tr><td>'.$spacer. $key .'</td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>';
    }
 }
}
```